# External source for sample rate of Redhawk system

Tags: redhawksdr

We are using Redhawk for an FM modulator. It reads an audio modulating signal from a file, performs the modulation, then sends the modulated data from Redhawk to an external program via TCP/IP for DAC and up-conversion to RF.

The data flows through the following components: rh.FileReader, rh.DataConverter, rh.fastfilter, an FM modulator, rh.DataConverter, and rh.sinksocket. The FM modulator is a custom component. 
The rh.sinksocket sends data to an external server program that sends the samples from Redhawk to an FPGA and DAC.

At present the sample rate appears to be controlled via the rh.FileReader component. However, we would like the external DAC to set the sample rate of the system, not the rh.FileReader component of Redhawk, for example via TCP/IP flow control.

Is it possible to use an external DAC as the clock source for a Redhawk waveform?

Answer (score 1):

The property on FileReader dictating the sample rate is simply telling it what the sample rate of the provided file is. This is used for the Signal Related Information (SRI) passed to down stream components and then output rate if you do not block or throttle. Eg. FileReader does not do any resampling of the given file to meet the sample rate given.

If you want to resample to a given rate you can try the ArbitraryRateResampler component.

Regarding setting these properties via some external mechanism (TCP/IP) you would want to write a specific component or REDHAWK service that listens for this external event and then makes a configure call to set the property you'd like changed.

If these events are global and can apply to many applications on your domain then a service is the right pattern, if these events are specific to a single application then a component might make more sense.